# How to prevent insert of data that is passed using query string in sails.js for post request?

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo, sails-postgresql, sails.io.js, sails-orientdb

I have created new table in mysql also created model and controller in sails.js. Now I am trying to insert data using sails. As we know when we create new modal in sails it will create new post, get and other api for us by default.

Now I am trying to insert data using post api using query string and request.body and both are working But **I need to insert data into db that is passed using request.body instead of request.querystring data in post request.** 
How can I do it???

1. Post data using query string in post request => working fine

[image: Post data using query string]

2. Post data using request.body in post request => **working fine (I want to insert data using this way only)**

   [image: Post data using request.body]

Same question I asked here https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails and https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/6918

Comment: if you pass data using POST request, then u can get using `req.body`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I know that we can do when we create api endpoint manually but here i haven't created endpoint it is created by sails. (I created model and controller by command line).

Answer (score 0):

sails uses Waterline, this performs sanitation by itself, you should be fine whenever you are using some of this built-in model [methods](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models):

```
.find()
.findOne()
.updateOne() 
.archiveOne()
.destroyOne()
.create()
.createEach()
.count()
.sum()
.avg()
.addToCollection()
.removeFromCollection()
```

As an extra layer of security you can check that the providing data types are correct and verify range, characters, etc. There are also [policies](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies) which allow you to restrict certain actions to logged-in users only.

hope this was helpful :)

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur there I added a list with the built-in model methods that answer the core issue of the question. The rest of information in those links is to wide and not strictly necessary.

Answer (score -1):

When you create an API by command line, you'll get an API that lets you search, paginate, sort, filter, create, destroy, update, and associate. Since these blueprint actions are built-in Sails. You can override these actions by yourself. 
Find more at in [Sails.js Documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints/blueprint-actions)